# IconPadding property on an ErrorProvider doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

So I am trying to make a space between an icon used for validation of a form and a textbox. Right now, I in Properties Window, I am setting ErrorProvider's `IconPadding` property (under ContainerControl section) to something like 5 but it doesn't make a difference. If matters, the icon I use is 48x48, so it doesn't have a preferred size, but I will change that later (to 16x16).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
this.errorProvider.SetIconPadding(this.textBox, 5);
```

Comment: Actually if I do this but with positive value, the icon goes where it should. Still, this is per control (eg. I have to do this for all textboxes separately). I thought that I can set this up on error provider instance itself to affect all of  the controls.

Comment: well, i am not sure how you could do that